# Change sizing defaults for data types in SSIS

Tags: sql, ssis, types, sql-server-2008-r2, defaults

I have a SSIS package with approximately fifty data flows in it that interacts with an Oracle database.

We changed data types in Oracle database for about 55 tables / 300+ columns from `FLOAT` to `NUMBER (30, 15)`

I am now working on changing the data types in the SSIS package.

Every time I change a column from `FLOAT` to `NUMBER` in a `DATA CONVERSION` component, it defaults to `NUMBER (10, 0)`.

Is there a way for me to change this so that the default comes up as `NUMBER (30, 15)`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that this is possible, you can save yourself a little bit of pain by using text expander / replacer program like Breevy:  http://www.16software.com/breevy/